# How can I tell if a rectangular matrix has duplicate rows in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates

I have an n-by-m rectangular matrix (n != m). What's the best way to find out if there are any duplicate rows in it in MATLAB? What's the best way to find the indices of the duplicates?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use unique() to find the distinct row values. If you end up with fewer rows, there are duplicates. It'll also give you indexes of one location of each of the distinct values. All the other row indexes are your duplicates.

```
x = [
    1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    4 4
    2 2
    3 3
    3 3
    ];
[u,I,J] = unique(x, 'rows', 'first')
hasDuplicates = size(u,1) < size(x,1)
ixDupRows = setdiff(1:size(x,1), I)
dupRowValues = x(ixDupRows,:)
```

Comment: Does anyone know the algorithm Matlab uses to compute this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the functions [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [SETDIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html) to accomplish this:

```
>> mat = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 7 8 9; 1 2 3];    %# Sample matrix
>> [newmat,index] = unique(mat,'rows','first');  %# Finds indices of unique rows
>> repeatedIndex = setdiff(1:size(mat,1),index)  %# Finds indices of repeats

repeatedIndex =

     4     5
```

Comment: Shouldn't `repeatedIndex` be `[3,4]`?

Comment: @AB: No, the fourth and fifth rows of `mat` are repeats of earlier rows.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the rows of the matrix, and for each pair, test if

`row1 == row2`

Comment: This works, but is definitely both slower and more verbose than the other basic option (i.e. using 'unique()').

Answer (score 0):

Say your matrix is M:

```
[S,idx1] = sortrows(M);
idx2 = find(all(diff(S,1) == 0,2));
out = unique(idx1([idx2;idx2+1]));
```

out will contain the duplicate row indices if any.

Comment: This will only work if your duplicated rows are next to one another.

Comment: Well, technically the OP never *explicitly* said whether or not the duplicated rows abut one another. Although not as general as using UNIQUE, this solution runs *substantially* faster in the specific case of neighboring duplicates, so +1.

Comment: Well, your new answer is doing something that I don't think the OP wanted. It is returning the indices of *all* rows that are not unique. I think the OP just wanted indices of duplicates *not counting* the first one found. In other words, if rows 2, 4, and 5 are the same, then rows 4 and 5 are considered "duplicates", with row 2 being the "original" (or 2 and 4 could be counted as duplicates, with 5 as the original... there was no order specified by the OP).