# how to compare to a row in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix similar to this one:

```
1468    1468

1468    1711

1468    1469

1711    1468

1711    1711

1711    1469

1469    1468

1469    1711

1469    1469
```

and I would like to remove the entry (i,j) iff the entry (j,i) exists. For example, I would like to remove `1711   1468` as `1468   1711` appears above it.

How do I do this?

Comment: What if there are two entries (i,j)? Should they also be removed?

Comment: Good. My solution will do that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the order doesn't matter for removing rows, you can combine [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) and [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) like this:

```
m = [1468    1468
1468    1711
1468    1469
1711    1468
1711    1711
1711    1469
1469    1468
1469    1711
1469    1469]

[~,v]=unique(sort(m,2),'rows');

trimmedM = m(sort(v),:) %# keep the row ordering as in the original

trimmedM =
        1468        1468
        1711        1468
        1711        1711
        1469        1468
        1469        1711
        1469        1469
```

Note that `unique` will retain the last of the duplicate entries, which seems to fit with your requirements.

Comment: Ooh.  Very nice.  Mine is painful by comparison.  (Apparently I can't vote down my own advice.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume by the nature of the problem that order is irrelevant.  Then you could just store the smaller number in the first column and look for duplicate rows.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510030/how-can-i-tell-if-a-rectangular-matrix-has-duplicate-rows-in-matlab) has some suggestions for that.  This line will perform that sort so the referenced methods will work:

```
x = [min(x(:,1),x(:,2)),max(x(:,1),x(:,2))]
```